# Google Maps My Places in MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Is there a way to load a Google Maps My Places map [(Can be created here)](http://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces) into a mapview on android? I think these are the same as "my maps".

I have many maps preloaded there and need to display them in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the My Places map as KML (there's a link in the UI). There is no default way of adding KML to a MapView, but you could parse the KML and add it as an [Overlay](http://goo.gl/fwvbK).

More info here:

[How to use kml file on mapView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848445/how-to-use-kml-file-on-mapview-in-android)